# How to keep the input field disabled upon refresh as well?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am disabling the input field after the user enters the data and submits. But, if we refresh or press ctl+F5 the disabled fields enables and becomes editable. Below is the code I have, what should I do to keep it disabled even upon refresh? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('firstname').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('lastname').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
  };
</script>
```

I am using localstorage to store the data

Comment: After refresh the page, the data filled in the input will be gone. So should you disabled it?

Comment: You need to save the state in local storage of browser or cookie to keep the state after refresh.

Comment: On submit, set flag into php session or use browser storage to track the same and disable input on page load itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest solution is to use sessionStorage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const disableInputs = function() {
    sessionStorage.disableInputs = 'true';
    document.getElementById('firstname').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('lastname').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
  };
  if (sessionStorage.disableInputs === 'true') disableInputs();
  document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = disableInputs;
</script>
```

If you want the disable effect to last past the session, use `localStorage` instead.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, just an awesome piece of code. It worked for me!!

Comment: But I want to change 'myButton' to checkbox, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use sessionStorage :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var disable = function() {
        document.getElementById('firstname').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('lastname').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
        sessionStorage.setItem("isDisabled", true);
      };
    document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = disable;
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("isDisable") === 'true') {
      disable();//call your function
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Put the setting inside

COOKIE version

```
function disablefield(){
        document.getElementById('firstname').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('lastname').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
}
        document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {

           $.cookie("is_disable", 1);
           disablefield();
        };

        if ($.cookie("is_disable")==1) disablefield();


      </script>
```

Session version

```
   function disablefield(){
            document.getElementById('firstname').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('lastname').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('email').disabled = true;
    }
            document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
               $.session.set("is_disable", "1");
               disablefield();
            };

            if ($.session.get("is_disable")==1) disablefield();


          </script>
```

Comment: There's no jQuery in the question.

Comment: Cookies are for information that needs to be communicated to the server. This, being client-side state management, is not the right time to use cookies.

Comment: No need for jQuery in a simple case like this.